# How to read pdf annotations in Zathura?

Tags: pdf, zathura

I opened a pdf with annotations (created in evince) with Zathura, and I see the little yellow sign for notes at the right place, but how to open them?

It seems that there is a [commit](https://git.pwmt.org/pwmt/zathura-pdf-mupdf/commit/5980f8fa11d0a7e7d1d309ad18def140766e4916) about it, but in the man page I can't find a shortcut or command.

Is it possible?

Comment: The commit you mentioned is about `zathura-pdf-mupdf` which is a rendering engine you can use in combination with zathura. There is `zathura-pdf-poppler` as well which can be used for pdf rendering.  Both of them have support for pdf annotations but zathura doesn't.

Comment: So does that mean zathura doesn't have a shortcut to open them? Or should I look into the Girara library, which is for the interface?

Comment: Correct, zathura doesn't support annotations at all and there is no way to open them.

Answer (score 2):

## No, it is not posible

You can't read anotations as zathura doesn't support anotations at all, so there is no way to open them.

Taken from [ploth's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/224687/ploth) to make a actual answer